# How to get related records for a single record in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

I have a `registration` table where the situation is that I have a table for `months` and a table for `years`. The relationship between `months` and `registration` is `one-to-many` and same is the case with `years` and `registration` like below:

//Here is the registration migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('registrations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('father_name');
        $table->string('contact1');
        $table->string('contact2')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->integer('day');
        $table->unsignedInteger('month_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('year_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Below is the `Registration` model:

```
class Registration extends Model
{
protected $fillable =
    ['name', 'father_name', 'contact1', 'contact2', 'address', 'amount',
        'day', 'month_id', 'year_id'
    ];

public function month()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Month::class);
}

public function year()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Year::class);
}
}
```

This is `Month` model:

```
class Month extends Model
{
public function registration()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Registration::class);
}
}
```

This is `Year` model:

```
class Year extends Model
{
public function registration()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Registration::class);
}
}
```

Now, when I want to show one `registration` record with its relationships like below, I get all the registration records instead of one.

```
public function show(Registration $reg)
{
    $registration = $reg::with('month', 'year')->get();
    return ['registration' => $registration];
}
```

When I used `with` function with modal name then I get all records correctly but when I use it even with the single instance of the modal, I still get all the related records which I don't want. I want to select the `Month` and `Year` related to the single instance of the `registration`.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: You don't have to create a Month and a Year model, just use the `created_at` column on registrations table. You can look for users who have registered in 2020 by a simple query.

Comment: @WebPajooh : Yes you are right, but this is a different situation where I need to use Month and Year in separate tables.

Comment: If there's a difference between registration time and creating the record in the database, you can create a date column like `registered_at` . Anyway you don't need additional models for that at all.

Comment: @WebPajooh I dont use gregorian calendar here, I use Hejri-Shamsi which is something that does not have good support.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `->get();`

in `$reg` you have one instance but then you do but then you make a new request with `->get();` and `get` displays all records

Do it like this

```php
public function show($regId)
{
    $registration = Registration::with('month', 'year')->findOrFail($regId);
    return ['registration' => $registration];
}
```

Comment: It does not work bro, I tried it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```php
public function show(Registration $reg)
{
    $reg->load(['month', 'year']);
    return ['registration' => $reg];
}
```

You can also remove model binding and use `with()` for eager loading.

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $registration = Registration::with(['year', 'month'])
        ->firstWhere('id', $id);

    return ['registration' => $registration];
}
```

Comment: `->firstWhere` does not exist in laravel.

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani Of course it does:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Answer (score 0):

It think you don't have specified the foreign_key in relation.
Or you have to define the
foreign_key by

```
class Registration extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
       'name', 'father_name', 'contact1', 'contact2', 'address', 
        'amount','day', 'month_id', 'year_id'
   ];

   public function month()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Month::class,'month_id');
   }

   public function year()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Year::class,'year_id');
   }
}
```

May be it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the get() method will return an array of records that you can loop over and that's why you get them all. Have you tried using the first() method that will return exactly one record.

`$registration = $reg::with('month', 'year')->first();`

Comment: It will always show the first record in the table, I checked it